# Centering marker after closing infowindow in Google Map API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I'm looking for a way to re-center the map marker after closing the infowindow.  This is what I have and it's not working.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'closeclick', function() {        
map.panTo(marker.getPosition());        
});
```

I got it to work.  Here's the code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {  
map.panTo(marker.getPosition());            
});
```